# como reiniciar DataTable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Buenas esta vez tengo un DataTable en mi tabla para poder añadir un buscador, mostrar cierta cantidad de filas y separar mi tabla en paginas, la cosa es que al añadir, modificar o eliminar datos esos tres elementos (el buscador, el select para mostrar las filas y las paginas de mi tabla) desaparecen, intente reinicializar agregando "destroy:true" en el datatable y redefiniendo la variable y usando table.destroy() y table.fnDestroy(); pero ninguna de ellas funciona, ¿que puedo hacer?

```
tabla = $('#categorias').DataTable({
  "destroy":true,
  "paging": true,
  "lengthChange": true,
  "searching": true,
  "ordering": false,
  "info": true,
  "autoWidth": false,
  "responsive": true,
});

function reinicializar(){
if(tabla){
    tabla.destroy();
    tabla = $('#categorias').DataTable({
        "paging": true,
        "lengthChange": true,
        "searching": true,
        "ordering": false,
        "info": true,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "responsive": true,
    });
   }
}

</script>
```

si solo dejo el destroy:true me sale el aviso de que no puedo reinicializar, si coloco ambos no me da ningun error pero sigue sin mostrarme los datos

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que eliminarla de este modo:

```
$('#categorias').DataTable().destroy();
```

Y luego volver a crearla, bueno yo te dejo el como yo lo hago tú puedes agregar o quitar dependiendo que lo que uses.

```
                // código para volver a crear la tabla

                $('#tableGPSXDia').DataTable({
                    order: [[0, 'desc']],
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    buttons: [
                        'excelHtml5',
                        'csvHtml5',
                        'pdfHtml5'
                    ],
                    language: {
                       info : "Mostrando _START_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
                       infoFiltered : '(filtrado de _MAX_ registros totales)',
                       search: "Buscar:",
                       paginate: {
                            first: "Primero",
                            last: "Último",
                            next: "Siguiente",
                            previous: "Anterior",
                        },
                    },
                } ).draw();
```

Comment: buenas, gracias por tu respues pues..acabo de probar la solución y el jquery me arroja un alert diciendo "DataTables warning: table id=categorias - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3"

Comment: Revisa bien lo que haces tienes que destruir la tabla antes de iniciar una nueva en su lugar.

Comment: Primero ejecutas esta linea: $('#categorias').DataTable().destroy();                             la documentación que pegaste lo explica.

Comment: exactamente eso hice lo intente creando dos funciones una para destruir y una para crearla de nuevo y que se ejecuten cada vez que realizo una accion con la tabla (primero destruyendo y luego creando) pero nada, intente colocando ambas en una sola funcion y nada e intente colocarlas fuera sin funcione y nada